# Question about the index of a subgroup in $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{C} / K )$ with $K$ a number field.

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Suppose that $k_0$ is a number field with subfield $K$.  Set $[k_0 : K] = d$.

If $G = \mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{C} / K )$ and $H$ is the subgroup of $G$ which fixes $k_0$, is it true that $[G:H] = d$?

Edit: I think $[G:H] \geq d$ is easy.  Let $L$ a finite Galois extension of $K$ containing $k_0$.  If $G_0 = \mathrm{Aut}(L/K)$ and $H_0$ is the subgroup of $G_0$ fixing $k_0$, then $[G_0 : H_0] = d$.  Let $\{\sigma_i\}_1^d$ denote a complete set of coset reps for $H_0$ in $G_0$.  Extend each $\sigma_i$ to an automorphism $\hat{\sigma}_i$ of $\mathbb{C}$. Then $\{\hat{\sigma}_i H \}$ is a set of distinct cosets of $H$ in $G$.

It seems like equality might not hold because of the number of ways you can extend each $\sigma_i$. At the same time, $H$ contains every extension of each element in $H_0$ (and more?).  Is $H$ "large" enough to keep the index in check?